# Throwing reference and catching by reference C++

Tags: c++

The question is purely theoretical to learn the limit of what can be thrown as exception.
Can a reference be thrown? I do not think standard is clear about it. And if possible, then likely to be a reference to a heap object, not the one on the stack that would be out of scope at catch site? Would that work?

Comment: From the dup answer `There's no such thing as "throwing by reference". It is simply impossible. There's no syntax for that. Every time you try to "throw a reference", a copy of the referenced object is actually thrown.`

Comment: Thanks, user93353, I guess that answered my question.